# I create my own chrome extension but this is not opened

Tags: json

I create my own chrome extension with manifest file

```
{
    "name":"Sample",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Sample",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    
    "action":{
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popoup":"index.html"
    }
   
    
}
```

But this chrome extension is not open in my browser
Thank you in advance if anyone solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spelling mistakes of default popup in action:
This line

```
"default_popoup":"index.html"
```

updated to:

```
"default_popup":"index.html"
```